# Determining H264 GOP structure

Tags: mp4, h.264

I have H264 encoded video packed in MOV container. And need to find out GOP structure **M** and **N** values as they defined here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures, i.e. **M** is the distance between two anchor frames (I or P) and **N** is the distance between I-frames.

Is it possible to extract **M** and **N** from **SPS**/**PPS**? Or I have to read each frame of GOP and take frame type info from the slice header?